# Using regex to extract URL folder in Google Datastudio

Tags: regex, regex-group, looker-studio, re2

in my datastudio I'm currently trying to extract the URL folders and their subdirectories by using group parameters in separate calculated fields.

The first calculated field looks something like this:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page,'https?:\\/\\/.*?\\/(.*?)\\/.*')
```

for each folder level I'll move the group by one directory level (and so on...):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page,"https?:\\/\\/.*?\\/.*?\\/(.*?)\\/.*")
```

The problem is that every URL without a trailing slash at the end get's grouped as "null".
I tried to make the last trailing slash optional, but this wont work at all.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page,'https?:\\/\\/.*?\\/(.*?)\\/?.*')
```

Comment: Maybe you need `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, r'https?://[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)')`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QCB1LM/1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using negated character classes here.

To get the first subpart, you may use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, "https?://[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+")
                                              ^^^^^^^
```

To get the second one, you may use

```
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, "https?://[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)")
                                                     ^^^^^^^
```

Note you needn't escape the `/` char, it is not a special regex metacharacter.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QCB1LM/1).

Comment: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, r'https?://[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+')` will display "null".

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, https?://[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+')` will display the same as mentioned above.